# UI Doesn't update after SWR data does NEXTJS

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, swr

I have a simple project going on and it is smoothly working but I have failed to add a item delete button. My post request to add items is perfectly working but my delete items doesn't work. I chose to go with post instead of delete because of my api structure.

Repo: https://github.com/berkaydagdeviren/rl-revenue-calculator

```
const handleClick = async (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(totalCredit, 'total credit before')
    setTotalCredit([...totalCredit, credit])
    console.log(ref, 'refFFFFFFF')



    const currentDate = ref.current


    const options = {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(
        { date: currentDate, credits: credit }
      )
    }
    var responseClone;
    fetch(`api/hello?date=${ref.current}`, options)
      .then(res => {
        responseClone = res.clone();
        return res.json()
      }).then(data => {
        console.log(data, 'data')
      }).then(function (data) {
        // Do something with data
      }, function (rejectionReason) { // 3
        console.log('Error parsing JSON from response:', rejectionReason, responseClone); // 4
        responseClone.text() // 5
          .then(function (bodyText) {
            console.log('Received the following instead of valid JSON:', bodyText); // 6
          });
      });

    setCredit(0)
  }
```

This is working perfectly fine but this does not;

```
const handleItemDelete = async itemToBeDeleted => {
   
    console.log(itemToBeDeleted, "itemTobeDeleted")
    const options = {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(
        { date: ref.current, index: itemToBeDeleted }
      )
    }
    var responseClone;
    

    await fetch(`api/hello?date=${ref.current}`, options)
      .then(async res =>  {
        responseClone = res.clone();
        console.log(res, "res")
        return await res.json()
    // I used this to read server's response when it was giving parsing JSON error
      }).then(data => {
        console.log(data, 'data')
      }).then(function (data) {
        // Do something with data
      }, function (rejectionReason) { // 3
        console.log('Error parsing JSON from response:', rejectionReason, responseClone); // 4
        responseClone.text() // 5
          .then(function (bodyText) {
            console.log('Received the following instead of valid JSON:', bodyText); // 6
          });
      });
      const newTotalCredit = await data.find(item => item.date == ref.current).credits
      setTotalCredit(newTotalCredit)
      console.log("STATE UPDATED BEFORE DATA")
      
      
    }
```

This is where I reference handleItemDelete to;

```
credit.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            item > 0 ? 
                            React.Children.toArray(

                                <div>
                                
                                <span style={{ color: 'green' }}> +{item}C </span> 
                                <button onClick={() =>handleItemDelete(index)}>
                                    X
                                </button>
                                
                            </div>
                                )
                            : 
                            null
                            
                            )
                        })
                    }
```

And this is how I handle put request, again I can see that mongodb is updated after refresh but because ui didn't totalCredits' indexes are messed up and results in either no deletion or false deletion.

```
handler.put(async (req, res) => {
  let data = req.body
  console.log(typeof(data))
  if (data.index) {
    
    let {date, index} = req.body
    console.log(data.index, "data.index")
  await req.db.collection('credits').update({date: date}, {$unset: {["credits."+ index] : 1}})
  await req.db.collection('credits').update({date: date}, {$pullAll: {credits: [null]}})
  
  }
  

  await req.db.collection('credits').updateOne({date: data.date}, {$push: {credits: data.credits}})
  res.json(data)


  
  
})
```

I use SWR right in the index.js Home component

```
 export default function Home() 
{    
const [totalCredit, setTotalCredit] = useState([])   
const [credit, setCredit] = useState('')   
const ref = useRef(null);   
const [date, setDate] = useState(null);    
const { data } = useSWR('/api/hello', async (url) => {const response = await axios.get(url);     
return response.data;   }, 
{  refreshInterval: 1000,  revalidateOnMount: true });
```

Sorry if I'm not clear or providing wrong pieces of code please let me know. Thank you in advance!

Comment: _"I can see that mongodb is updated after refresh but because ui didn't totalCredits' indexes are messed up and results in either no deletion or false deletion"_ - To be clear, does this mean the data in the database gets deleted correctly, but the UI does not reflect the item deletion, even after the `refreshInterval` has passed?

Comment: Yes, excatly. I click on an item and it gets deleted in the database. But it stays on the ui. Then when i click on the same item, it gets deleted on the ui but because it was already deleted in db, indexes change and another item gets deleted. (most of the time)

Answer (score 0):

your options in `handleDeleteItem`:

```
const options = {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      },
```

Should not method be `DELETE`? You are sending `PUT` request instead of `DELETE`

Comment: I am using 
db.lists.update({}, {$unset : {"interests.3" : 1 }}) 
db.lists.update({}, {$pull : {"interests" : null}})
this method to delete by index and I assumed I would use put. Let me try.